# Can A Beta Ubuntu Build Randomly Shut Down?

Tags: ubuntu

I have been using ubuntu 11.04 beta for the past two months... I needed to use it because of the repositories/extensions exclusive to that build.

Every so often however (sometimes every few hours, sometimes every few weeks) it will randomly shut down.

At first I thought it had to do with the mild overclocking I had in place. So I removed it.

Everything was fine for a few weeks, and I just woke up to it being off again. Quite annoying!

Anybody know what could be the cause?

Comment: What is in the syslog leading up to the shutdown.  Is there any kernel dumps, are any errors logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the heat in your hardware? Is it all cleaned up?

Before installing 11.04, was your hardware running ok? If so, I suggest you to downgrade (or reinstall) 10.10, and build the packages you need by hand. You can look for PPAs also.

Answer (score 1):

Is this question for real?

You're seriously asking if beta code on an overclocked machine might be less stable than you'd expected, on a Q&A site for pro sysadmins?

Let's assume you're being serious, the answer would be; yes, I'd not expect that much stability, have you tried losing the overclocking and/or contributing to their dev efforts via a bug report?

Like you say, quite annoying!